# Reactflow custom node does not update global variable in zustand store (store.ts)

Tags: react-flow

I have written a code for a basic flow diagram that allows me to create an in theory editable flow chart system with nodes. I have a customNode.js file an app.js file and a store.js one. I have implemented using github as a node storage and it works so it is not relevant rn. The problem i am facing is that I have implemented editing in my customNode file which works for the ui meaning when i edit a text in a node i can see the edited result in the chart but even though I am trying to update the global state using the onNodeChange function, the global state is not getting updated as I can see in the console printed result. I am getting crazy

I have tried everything but nothing worked. For this simple code I am tryin to make it work for 3 days now and even chatgpt says it should work but it doesnt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.